# How To Make Relations Between Two Entities From Different Microservices In Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I am trying to make a simple **Spring Boot** web app using **Microservice Architecture**.

I have two microservices with entities as defined below:

```
Microservice 1 :

@Entity
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String Content;

}
```

and

```
Microservice 2 :

@Entity
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
}
```

Now I want to have a **Many To Many** relation between these two entities in my **Gateway**.

I had tried to use feign client as below:

```
Gateway :

@FeignClient(value = "article-service")
public interface ArticleClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/articles/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    Set<Article> getArticleById(@RequestParam("id") Long id);

}

@FeignClient(value = "tag-service")
public interface TagClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/tags/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    Tag getTagById(@RequestParam("id") Long id);

}
```

And defined **Article** and **Tag** entities in my **Gateway** like this:

```
Gateway :

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Entry {

    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String Content;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "article_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id",
                referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Tag> tags;
}


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Tag {
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Article> articles;
}
```

I have a table named **article_tag** in my database (**Postgres**).

Now how can I define my repositories in the **Gateway**?
How to write getArticlesByTagId() or getTagsByArticleId() functions?
I did whatever I could to make this relation work but I think they are not going to get along with each other :)

Comment: As far as I know, you don't define relations (since you won't have any). In stead of that, your gateway will only contain an entity for `article_tag` and you have to map the `article_id` and `tag_id` fields themselves. If you want to retrieve the articles for a specific tag, you look up the `article_id`s and pass them to the article microservice (REST call?) to retrieve the full blown articles.

Comment: Did you find proper solution to your problem?

Comment: The most common solution I've seen for this issue when using Microservice architecture (especially in a Spring Cloud environment) is to simply duplicate your code. Copy/paste the entity class in the microservice that needs a reference to it. From there, you have access to the reference you need in order to create a Join table, foreign key, etc.. There shouldn't be risk of the microservice having the ability to inadvertently insert/update or even query the table, so long as you do not create a repository for that entity as well...

Answer (score 3):

It just impossible what you want, you have 2 differents applications, each entity has its own life in its context. Imagine the case where a service is down, how would you do?

If a microservice is closely linked to another one, you should revise your architecture.

To solve this kind of problem, add an identifier in each entity to identify which Tag belongs to an Entry and vice-versa, you can request your data using those identifiers.